# Reference for some elementary facts about principal bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gauge-theory

Let $(P,\pi,B,G)$ be a principal bundle with total space $P$, base $B$, projection $\pi$ and structure group $G$.

Now I am searching for a good reference (with proofs) for the following facts:

1) The fundamental vector fields on $P$ span pointwise the vertical space - or equivalently they generate the $C^\infty(P)$-module of smooth sections of the vertical bundle.

2) Let $\gamma \colon TP \to \mathrm{Lie}(G)$ a connection one-form. The horizontal lifts of vector fields span pointwise the horizontal space - or equivalently they generate the $C^\infty(P)$-module of smooth sections of the horizontal bundle.

Comment: The first chapter of the book of Kobayashi-N*** "Foundations of differential geometry" 

Comment: Thanks, the exact references are: Kobayashi-N*** before Prop.I  5.1 and before Prop. II 1.2.

Any further reference?

Comment: For the second point, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34663/module-of-sections-of-the-horizontal-bundle

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at Sharpe's *differential geometry*, whose title makes it difficult to catch among all those books named the same, but is interested in Elie Cartan's point of view on geometric structures. It contains a lot of material on these topics, and tries to relate this to intuition in a nice manner.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the beautifully written book *Differential Geometry : Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic classes* by Loring Tu.